# Authorization for multiple access patterns

Tags: authorization, graphql

I have a GraphQL API built using Graphene and Flask. The API currently serves only as a backend for a website and contains operations like search, create order etc. Some operations are completely public, some are restricted to logged in users. At the moment, I use JWT tokens for user authentication. I would like to incorporate another level of authorization, and that is taking into account where from requests originate. All the examples I have seen use only one dimension -- users. Either there is a logged in user (possibly with some roles/scopes) or there is none. This is what I have implemented at the moment. However, I'd like to incorporate another dimension -- origin. A couple of examples:

- I would like to rate limit requests from unknown origins differently than requests from the website (trusted source).
- I would like to allow restricted operations (e.g. create anonymous order) from the website without user authentication but disallow this operation completely when the request origins from an unknown location.
- I would like to limit the number of search request results when a request comes to from an unknown location (dummy scraping prevention) while allowing unlimited results when it comes from the website.

There are a couple of approaches that I can think of, but I don't quite like any of them:

- Create two APIs - one public and one private (website only). That would IMHO lead to unnecessary duplication.
- Use the same login process even from a trusted website and assign some *admin* JWT token. This has the wrong semantics and isn't secure.

What's the de facto standard for how to solve this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use an API gateway - that's partly what they are for. Look into Kong or Apigee for instance. There are many more.

For basic access control e.g. anonymous vs. authenticated or throttling, they should be able to handle that. For additional authorization scenarios, look into attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)). It's a means to implement externalized authorization using policies written in [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa). That will let you handle any type of authorization. The company I work for, [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com), specializes in API authorization. We use ALFA and integrate with the likes of Kong (they do the interception).

Comment: Thanks for answer. This might help in solving the problem, but would bring too much overhead modifying the existing setup. What I'm seeking is a pattern that I could you to build a simple custom solution myself.

Comment: Custom is more work :-) the pattern I described is the way to go. If you cannot use an API gateway, look into the hooks that exist in your API framework so that you can intercept and authorize the calls

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm going to do, hence the question ;-) I'm asking what's they way to go in Graphene (+ Flask).